# Can XML comments on Android resources be automatically copied to R?

Tags: android, xml, resources

Is there any way to comment xml items of Android resources so that the comment is visible in Eclipses' IntelliSense when browsing 'R' class?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if there is a way it probably isn't through XML comments, as the vast majority of XML parsers don't even make comments visible to the client.

Answer (score 1):

If you place an xml comment above an element in an xml resource file, that comment will appear in the autogenerated code above the static final int.  Theoretically, this means eclipse could show the comment in intellisense.

They don't appear to though, I'm not sure why.  The comments don't look any different than comments on my own static final ints that do show up.